# how to classify a large csv file of signals without headers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, classification

i had a large csv file (3000*20000) of data without headers i added one columns to represent the classes. how i can fit the data to the model when the features has no headers and it can not be added manually due to the large number of columns.
is there i way to automatically iterate each columns in a row?

when i had a small file of 4 columns i used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.ExcelFile("bcs.xlsx")
col = [0, 1, 2, 3]
data = pd.parse(pd.sheet_names[0], parse_cols = col)

pdc = list(data["pdc"])
pds = list(data["pds"])
pdsh = list(data["pdsh"])
pd_class = list(data["class"])

features = []
for i in range(len(pdc)):
    features.append([pdc[i],pds[i],pdsh[i]])

labels = []
labels = pd_class
```

But with a 3000 by 20000 file i don't know how to identify the features and labels/target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a csv like that:

```
1,2,3,4,0
1,2,3,4,1
1,2,3,4,1
1,2,3,4,0
```

where the first 4 columns are features and the last one is the label or class you want. You can read the file with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) and create a dataframe for you features and one for your labels which you can fit next, to your model.

```
import pandas as pd

#CSV localPath
mypath ='C:\\...'

#The names of the columns you want to have in your dataframe
colNames = ['Feature1','Feature2','Feature3','Feature4','class']

#Read the data as dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = mypath, 
                 names = colNames , sep  = ',' , header = None)

#Get the first four columns as features
features = df.ix[:,:4]
#and last columns as label
labels = df['class']
```